# How to attach SD card files with apk

Tags: android, android-sdcard, apk, android-install-apk

My project have multiple files in SD card. But when I install apk file on phone it does not work.

Please tell me how to attach those files with apk.

Answer (score 1):

Your sdcard files cannot become the part of APK file, if you want those files to attach to your apk, insert them into `asset` folder or `raw` folder.

EDIT:

If you put your file in raw directory then:

```
com.your.package:raw/yourFile
```

Like this:

```
int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("com.your.package:raw/somefile.txt");
File f = new File(context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId));
```

And here's someone doing it with the `assets` folder:

Android Assets with sub folders

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("subfolder/somefile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a sqlite database and store the path of whatever files you want to store on the sdcard. Also you can store them in assets folder depending upon the type of file but it is not a good practice as many say.

Comment: Hey thats funny! same name and similar answer

Comment: just a coincidence Vijay :):)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the supporting files on a web server and have the application download the files to the sdcard on first run. This is what many games do. Google Play also offers free storage of files for applications.

Here is the Google blog post on large APK's

http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html